# How to update Media store after file is added or deleted from a directory

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have an interface to record and play the videos. After recording a new video it is not updated to  media store. The same problem I am facing while deleting a recorded file.

My question is:

How I can update the media store after adding or deleting a video file in a specific directory.

Thanks,
Dipesh

Comment: did you managed it to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Add this line after save or delete function

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: i have done same thing, but i am not able to store file in to mediastore. Please let me know if anything more to do other than this.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer it will not help to store file but it will send broadcast to Media  for any update

Comment: So how i get the images in media store that i have just captured and save to SDCard? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

See the `MediaScannerConnection`'s `scanFile` method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html

Comment: thanks for ur reply but i have already checked that approach it is not working. I was able to add files using contentValues but it is not working in case of deletion.

Comment: Have you tried scanning the directory that the file is in, not the specific file?

Comment: @Femi - I tried scanning the parent folder but in case of file deletion, this still didn't work.