# issue with ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument?

Tags: android, activityresultcontracts

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val save = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()) {
            Log.d("<debug>", "uri: $it")
        }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
            save.launch("file")
        }
    }
}
```

1. Navigating to the Download folder, only irrelevant files

[image]

2. Using the code above, saving 1 file

[image]

3. If I re-run the code to save a file again

[image]

4. Navigating to the Download folder

[image]

Basically, whenever I delete the file in Download and re-run the code, it displays all the previously created files, even though there's only 1 in there.

note: the issue persists even if I delete then reinstall the app or power cycle the device (pixel 3, pixel 6 both on android 12)

Comment: What happens when you use device file explorer or run `adb shell ls /sdcard/Download` after each change? Is this just a disparity/issue with the files application where its not updating changes to the Download folder correctly.

Comment: @Mark the content of `/sdcard/Download` is consistent with the expected behavior (0 file before running the code, 1 file afterwards). The issue seems to be with whatever file app `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()` is launching.

Comment: I see - can you "pull down to refresh" in the Files app when it shows the wrong contents?

Comment: @Mark this has no effect. I also made sure to remove the hidden `.trashed-` files.

Comment: I'd try killing the Files app process between deletions and file ccreations via your code - probably just a caching/update issue for the Files App process or Files Actvity thats opened from the contract .. a solution, not sure off top my head.. this might work, but its old and Android have meesed around with the storage framework 50 times since the SO post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13101630/4252352

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you would usually call `registerForActivityResult` outside of `onCreate`, as a class member (`private var save = registerForActivityResult...`) ([examples/docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register)). Usually that would generate an error though if it's called too late, but maybe it's messing up something weird with the files?